# Django not storing sessions in older browsers

Tags: python, django, internet-explorer, web-applications

My application (Django 1.3) cannot seem to store session data in the following browsers:

```
<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CSRF_COOKIE': 'dsfdfsdfsdf',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-us',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=3600',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'www.dxxx.com',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
 'HTTP_VIA': '1.0 wtp-gd-maya2.iad1:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '127.0.0.1, xx.xxx.xx.xx',
 'PATH_INFO': u'xxxxx',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': 'xxxx',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': ' xx.xxx.xx.xx',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '80',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'www.xxxxx.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/0.14.2',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x2ac0ec0>,
 'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.glogging.LazyWriter object at 0x2588650>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at 0x2608668>,
 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x2b47d50>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

The session variable name has an underscore in it "unique_id" but am I correct in looking at this Request and seeing it is coming from someone using IE6 + WinNT?

Can anyone help me out here and let me know why Django might be having trouble in this browser?

Thanks

Comment: The older browser in question has cookies enabled, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's either IE6 on Win NT 5.1 (aka Windows XP) or anything else with a spoofed `User-Agent`.

Comment: how do i know if it has cookies enabled from this request ?

Comment: @JosephMisiti you don't.